# It is possible to use a variable as a "key" in a realtime Firebase Database. UNITY c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to send a variable as a key in firebase, but it doesn't work, I always have to send a specific string.

[image]
[image]

It just works fine, but when sending a variable as a key it doesn't work.

[image]

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Aside from that, you'll want to either log the value of `dateOfRecord` right before the call to Firebase, or (even better) set a breakpoint on the line that calls Firebase and run in a debugger to check the variable.

Comment: Thanks for that first text formating advice, next time I will follow. Anyways Im 100% sure, that the variable is okay and "prints" the string correctly. Before calling the Firebase function, I had there a debug.log that checked value of `dateOfRecord` and it was fine.

Comment: so its printing "0" ? when you say it doesnt work what does it say

Comment: Not really, "0" was just an example if it even working with direct send "string" not variable. So to summarize, if I send a "Variable" which is a string, Firebase doesn't authenticate and do not make a record and if I insert a string directly, the record create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, the "Key" of the Firebase database can't accept some characters, and I was sending the date as a key with dots, which is not allowed. So I replaced the dots with underscores.

```
string safeDateOfRecord = dateOfRecord.Replace(".", "_");
```